# Capture long press or tap hold event of grid row in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am using rowcontextmenu event of grid to display some options on right click which is working fine on desktop. In iPad i want to implement same functionality on long press but i dint found any such event in sencha docs. I have tried jquery long press plugin but couldn't achieve it.
I am using Ext JS 3.4 version. Any hints please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these listeners (at least) have to be applied to the [Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel), so that these events are being properly bound within that particular scope. see this [blog article](https://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-on-tap/); there are a bunch more DOM event types to consider. the event you are looking for is either called `taphold` or `longpress` (see the [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) documentation for "Handling Events").

the events of the `RowSelectionModel` can be defined alike:

```
new Ext.grid.GridPanel({

    /**
     * one has to instance the default row-selection model explicitly,
     * in order to be able to configure it's event listeners ...
    **/
    sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
        singleSelect: true,
        listeners: {

            taphold: 'rowcontextmenu'

        }
    })

});
```

one can also use [Ext.util.Observable](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable) to debug events; this comes handy, especially when using a dated framework, where it is rather questionable, in how far the functionality was already supported.

```
// to intercept all events:
Ext.util.Observable.prototype.fireEvent = 
Ext.util.Observable.prototype.fireEvent.createInterceptor(function() {
    console.log(this.name);
    console.log(arguments);
    return true;
});

// to capture the events of a particular component:
Ext.util.Observable.capture(
    Ext.getCmp('my-grid-component'), function(event) {
        console.info(event);
    }
);
```

with [Ext.EventManager.addListener()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.EventManager-method-addListener) or [.on()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.EventManager-method-on), one can define just any missing framework events.

Comment: taphold and longpress are not available in Ext 3. I tried with second option its giving createInterceptor of undefined error. While debugging it has a value, but after executing its breaking somewhere in the framework.

Comment: @Jaydeep according to the documentation, the `Ext.util.Observable` should at least exist... while one use `Ext.EventManger` to define the browser events as framework events, so they become known and are being fired (only then one can rebind them, alike in the first example). adding the missing events to the outdated framework is the least to have them being fired... upgrading to later framework versions most likely would require general code refactoring.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/source/Observable.html#Ext-util-Observable-method-fireEvent ...is certainly defined; eventually the `Ext.getCmp()` is being passed a wrongful name ? one can also test that in the console, if it can find the component - whether or not.

Comment: Grid object i am passing is correct, createInterceptor is giving some error. But while debugging i can see that object, after execution its giving error that too in framework file.. any idea why it is behaving so?